# Client call back in ASP.NET has very strange behavior

Tags: vb.net

I have code:
A.ascx file:

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="A.ascx.vb" Inherits="ABC.A" %>
<script  type="text/javascript">

function GetCallback(pResult) {

}
</script>
```

A.ascx.vb file:

```
Namespace ABC
    Partial Class A
        Implements System.Web.UI.ICallbackEventHandler
Private _callbackResult As String
Public Sub RaiseCallbackEvent(ByVal pArg As String) _
            Implements System.Web.UI.ICallbackEventHandler.RaiseCallbackEvent

            _callbackResult = GetData(pArg) 'GetData is a function return a string

        End Sub

Public Function GetCallbackResult() As String _
            Implements System.Web.UI.ICallbackEventHandler.GetCallbackResult
            Return _callbackResult
        End Function
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

If Not IsPostBack Then
               ddlProject.Attributes.Add("onchange", "Callback(document.getElementById('" & ddlProject.ClientID & "').options[document.getElementById('" & ddlProject.ClientID & "').selectedIndex].value);")
                Dim cbReference As String = Page.ClientScript.GetCallbackEventReference(Me, "arg", "GetCallback", "context")
                Dim cbScript As String = "function Callback(arg,context)" & "{" & cbReference & ";" & "}"
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "Callback", cbScript, True)
End If
End Sub
```

The problem is when I change value in dropbox `ddlProject`, `GetCallback` has been never fired.
I debug that `GetCallbackResult` is called. When the following code executes:

```
function WebForm_ExecuteCallback(callbackObject) {
    var response = callbackObject.xmlRequest.responseText;
    if (response.charAt(0) == "s") {
        if ((typeof(callbackObject.eventCallback) != "undefined") && (callbackObject.eventCallback != null)) {
            callbackObject.eventCallback(response.substring(1), callbackObject.context);
        }
    }
```

The `response` isn't starting with "s" or "e". It has a strange string append at the beginning of `_callbackResult` string value

```
ASP.abc_a_ascx1628|/wEdAEqgbfF05ggvbuBJkShRMuTf78aRWoCDixU4f5xZuwoiGiX5AzDOb/8AeBWl0clV3VND0U6Mhi/CYl90Bs4fMAg7x09VCodiazH2hPts
```

Please kindly shed me a light. I am a newbie at ASP.NET.
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: When request to server, file name ASP.abc_a_ascx is automatically appended to response. How can I turn it off? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In web page file:

```
Response.Write(usercontrol)
```

So it write user control name in the web page before html content.
It made client callback invalid too.
I just comment this line. The problem is resolved.
The remain things doubt is why this doesn't happen in production environment.